# Detection result not displayed in YOLO

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, yolo

I'm newest in YOLO.
I compile darknet in windows.>>darknet.exe

-Visual studio 2019

- open cv 3.4
- cuda 10.2

I tried to execute sample code.

`> darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights data/dog.jpg`

Code is runnning correctly and the prediction figure is shown, but detected result is not shown in the figure.
[image: Predictions.jpg]

evaluation result (ex.dog 100%) may not be not calculated.

Log

```
C:\dev\darknet-master\build\darknet\x64> darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights  data/dog.jpg
 CUDA-version: 10020 (11000), cuDNN: 8.0.5, CUDNN_HALF=1, GPU count: 1
 CUDNN_HALF=1
 OpenCV version: 4.3.0
 0 : compute_capability = 750, cudnn_half = 1, GPU: GeForce GTX 1650
net.optimized_memory = 0
mini_batch = 1, batch = 1, time_steps = 1, train = 0
   layer   filters  size/strd(dil)      input                output
   0 conv     32       3 x 3/ 1    416 x 416 x   3 ->  416 x 416 x  32 0.299 BF
   1 conv     64       3 x 3/ 2    416 x 416 x  32 ->  208 x 208 x  64 1.595 BF
   2 conv     32       1 x 1/ 1    208 x 208 x  64 ->  208 x 208 x  32 0.177 BF
   3 conv     64       3 x 3/ 1    208 x 208 x  32 ->  208 x 208 x  64 1.595 BF
   4 Shortcut Layer: 1,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs: 208 x 208 x  64 0.003 BF
   5 conv    128       3 x 3/ 2    208 x 208 x  64 ->  104 x 104 x 128 1.595 BF
   6 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    104 x 104 x 128 ->  104 x 104 x  64 0.177 BF
   7 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1    104 x 104 x  64 ->  104 x 104 x 128 1.595 BF
   8 Shortcut Layer: 5,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs: 104 x 104 x 128 0.001 BF
   9 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    104 x 104 x 128 ->  104 x 104 x  64 0.177 BF
  10 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1    104 x 104 x  64 ->  104 x 104 x 128 1.595 BF
  11 Shortcut Layer: 8,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs: 104 x 104 x 128 0.001 BF
  12 conv    256       3 x 3/ 2    104 x 104 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
  13 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
  14 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
  15 Shortcut Layer: 12,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 256 0.001 BF
  16 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
  17 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
  18 Shortcut Layer: 15,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 256 0.001 BF
  19 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
  20 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
  21 Shortcut Layer: 18,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 256 0.001 BF
  22 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
  23 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
  24 Shortcut Layer: 21,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 256 0.001 BF
  25 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
  26 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
  27 Shortcut Layer: 24,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 256 0.001 BF
  28 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
  29 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
  30 Shortcut Layer: 27,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 256 0.001 BF
  31 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
  32 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
  33 Shortcut Layer: 30,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 256 0.001 BF
  34 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
  35 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
  36 Shortcut Layer: 33,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 256 0.001 BF
  37 conv    512       3 x 3/ 2     52 x  52 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
  38 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
  39 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
  40 Shortcut Layer: 37,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 512 0.000 BF
  41 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
  42 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
  43 Shortcut Layer: 40,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 512 0.000 BF
  44 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
  45 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
  46 Shortcut Layer: 43,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 512 0.000 BF
  47 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
  48 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
  49 Shortcut Layer: 46,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 512 0.000 BF
  50 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
  51 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
  52 Shortcut Layer: 49,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 512 0.000 BF
  53 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
  54 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
  55 Shortcut Layer: 52,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 512 0.000 BF
  56 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
  57 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
  58 Shortcut Layer: 55,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 512 0.000 BF
  59 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
  60 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
  61 Shortcut Layer: 58,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 512 0.000 BF
  62 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 2     26 x  26 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x1024 1.595 BF
  63 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.177 BF
  64 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x1024 1.595 BF
  65 Shortcut Layer: 62,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  13 x  13 x1024 0.000 BF
  66 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.177 BF
  67 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x1024 1.595 BF
  68 Shortcut Layer: 65,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  13 x  13 x1024 0.000 BF
  69 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.177 BF
  70 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x1024 1.595 BF
  71 Shortcut Layer: 68,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  13 x  13 x1024 0.000 BF
  72 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.177 BF
  73 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x1024 1.595 BF
  74 Shortcut Layer: 71,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  13 x  13 x1024 0.000 BF
  75 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.177 BF
  76 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x1024 1.595 BF
  77 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.177 BF
  78 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x1024 1.595 BF
  79 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.177 BF
  80 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x1024 1.595 BF
  81 conv    255       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 255 0.088 BF
  82 yolo
[yolo] params: iou loss: mse (2), iou_norm: 0.75, obj_norm: 1.00, cls_norm: 1.00, delta_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.00
  83 route  79                                     ->   13 x  13 x 512
  84 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 256 0.044 BF
  85 upsample                 2x    13 x  13 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256
  86 route  85 61                                  ->   26 x  26 x 768
  87 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 768 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.266 BF
  88 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
  89 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
  90 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
  91 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
  92 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
  93 conv    255       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 255 0.177 BF
  94 yolo
[yolo] params: iou loss: mse (2), iou_norm: 0.75, obj_norm: 1.00, cls_norm: 1.00, delta_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.00
  95 route  91                                     ->   26 x  26 x 256
  96 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 128 0.044 BF
  97 upsample                 2x    26 x  26 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128
  98 route  97 36                                  ->   52 x  52 x 384
  99 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 384 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.266 BF
 100 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
 101 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
 102 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
 103 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
 104 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
 105 conv    255       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 255 0.353 BF
 106 yolo
[yolo] params: iou loss: mse (2), iou_norm: 0.75, obj_norm: 1.00, cls_norm: 1.00, delta_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.00
Total BFLOPS 65.879
avg_outputs = 532444
 Allocate additional workspace_size = 18.88 MB
Loading weights from yolov3.weights...
 seen 64, trained: 32013 K-images (500 Kilo-batches_64)
Done! Loaded 107 layers from weights-file
 Detection layer: 82 - type = 28
 Detection layer: 94 - type = 28
 Detection layer: 106 - type = 28
data/dog.jpg: Predicted in 629.940000 milli-seconds.
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: @tadman Thank you for your advice. I paste the text in command prompt.

Comment: I encountered exactly the same problem. Do you know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When you execute this command, it generates a file named predictions.jpg.
In it are the bounding boxes in the images.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I actually got a file named predictions.jpg.(I attached this file in my question)
However, there is no bounding boxes in the images.
If you have more advices , I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I like to follow this link step by step.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_GdoqCJWXsChrOiY8sZMr_zbr_fH-0Fg
I believe it is the same steps for linux and windows

Comment: Thank you for your  advice. I'll try step by step by following the link.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I must remove CUDNN_HALF from the pre-processors list in MS Visual Studio. PROBLEM SOLVED!

Answer (score 0):

It's also important to add a threshold in the end of the line:

---

darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights data/dog.jpg **thresh -0.5 -ext_output**

---

If nothing appears, you can change the value. For example, to -0.3